# How to use postcss (lost grid) in vue-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, postcss

I'm experimenting with Vue2 and have a question on using lost-grid (http://lostgrid.org/) in my app. Lost-grid is a postcss grid-system and I've been able to use this numerous times in react apps with webpack2.

How can I use lost-grid i with vue-loader? I've installed 'lost' through npm, and tried different ways of adding the postcss loader. Nothing seems to work and the documentation isn't very helpful either.

Here is the business part of webpack.base.conf.js (as I undersrtand it, all the css loading is run through the vue-loader):

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {

...
```

vue-loader.conf.js looks like:

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: isProduction
      ? config.build.productionSourceMap
      : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
    extract: isProduction
  })
}
```

utils.js looks like this:

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

exports.assetsPath = function (_path) {
  var assetsSubDirectory = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? config.build.assetsSubDirectory
    : config.dev.assetsSubDirectory
  return path.posix.join(assetsSubDirectory, _path)
}

exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  var cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }

  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {
    var loaders = [cssLoader]
    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      })
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: loaders,
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
      })
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
    }
  }

  // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/configurations/extract-css.html
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(''),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}

// Generate loaders for standalone style files (outside of .vue)
exports.styleLoaders = function (options) {
  var output = []
  var loaders = exports.cssLoaders(options)
  for (var extension in loaders) {
    var loader = loaders[extension]
    output.push({
      test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
      use: loader
    })
  }
  return output
}
```

Question now is... where do I put what? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following lines to the vue-loader.config.js file in build/

```
postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 7 versions']
    })
]
```

so it looks like this:

```
 module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: isProduction ? config.build.productionSourceMap : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
    extract: isProduction
  }),
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      browsers: ['last 7 versions']
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

require('lost') should add to the postcss Array like above

Answer (score -1):

"browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 8"
    ]

In package.json have define, you can see https://github.com/ai/browserslist#config-file